# Adding `Content-Length` header to POST request using clj-http.lite?

Tags: clojure, clj-http

I just shifted from using `clj-http`  to `clj-http.lite` . The code used for uploading a file with multipart that worked with `clj-http`  does not seem to work with `clj-http-lite` . With the later I get an error

```
POST requests require a <code>Content-length</code> header.  <ins>That's all we know.</ins>
```

I tried adding the content length header explicitly but still get the same error (http status code 411)
Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: Maybe it's this bug? https://github.com/hiredman/clj-http-lite/issues/13 ... please edit your question stating the versions of the libraries that you are using and a minimal example to understand what did you try and what doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: @DenisFuenzalida The Hiredman repo has been archived. So, I raised the issue in the repo by `martinklepsch`. The issue is raised here and it contains all the details - https://github.com/martinklepsch/clj-http-lite/issues/5